# Checking killed processes on Linux

Tags: linux, process, kill-process

I found a couple of processes killed on a server running Debian. I can confirm that the machine was not restarted. I was wondering if there was a way to check the killed processes on the machine.

I have the required permissions.

Comment: What's m/c? I'm not familiar with the term, and I only come up with "Midnight Commander" in Google.

Comment: m/c being?... That is a question for serverfault, but anyway --> look in the logs

Comment: m/c == machine! Sorry for the confusing terminology. I checked the kern.log but it didn't mention any specific details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `systemtap` to track signal origins and destinations.  Setting up `systemtap` on your system is not trivial, but well worth the effort IMO.

Here's an example probe to track `SIGKILL` (from [the examples](http://sourceware.org/systemtap/examples/process/sigkill.stp) ):

```
probe signal.send {
  if (sig_name == "SIGKILL")
    printf("%s was sent to %s (pid:%d) by %s uid:%d\n",
           sig_name, pid_name, sig_pid, execname(), uid())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://djangstorm.com/Content/pkill.html. pkill -e will help in this case.

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/338114) so other users will have some idea what it is the link about. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.